# NXT program not running

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, motor

We have multiple NXT Bricks. We can read sensor data and motor degrees from View. Some are running FW 1.31, others FW 1.28.

When we try a simple 5-step NXT program, the motors will not turn. We tries wait blocks after the move blocks. This only occurs on some of the bricks, and there is no correlation with the FW version.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use in program the same motors as you check via View? For example, maybe you view A and B motors, but in program uses C and D?
If you have the following behaviour:

> You check motors via View, then create a program and it works. After
>   that you substitute NXT brick for another one, check the same motors
>   via View but that same program doesn't work.

In that case I'd suggest to refresh firmware.

Comment: We made sure to use the correct motor ports when checking view and running the program. We will try refreshing the firmware.